# Google Admob GDPR compliance - Unity

Tags: unity, admob

I have created a unity game that uses admob to show only rewarded video ads and there are no banner/interstitial ads in my game. Is it mandatory to take user consent (for EU countries) for showing the rewarded ads and if so how do I go about implementing it. I followed some online tutorials to implement admob ads but there was no mention of gdpr in any of those. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that issue is handled by AdMob itself. When an ad is showing, there's an icon for privacy. Click that, and it takes you to the stuff that makes it GDPR compliant.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of this we could look at, or a statement from the documentation relating to this aspect?